# sudo apt-get update: CD-ROM does not have a release file

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates

I get the following error running `apt-get update`:

```
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Try this: Open "Software and Updates" and look at the "Ubuntu Software" tab.  Down at the bottom, if the CD-ROM box is ticked, untick it, and try again.

Comment: There are no packages included in the Ubuntu live DVD´s. A live DVD is an image of an installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use a CD as a repository. You can't do that in this way, because the CD doesn't have the necessary structure. If you want to make a CD accessible to  APT, you have to use `apt-cdrom`. You can find further information on `apt-cdrom`s man page

```
man apt-cdrom
```

And, no offence meant, but the error messages you quoted in your question literally tell you just that:

> Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs